# ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jdwp

```
[junit] FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197) 
[junit] ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use 
[junit] ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510) 
[junit] JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750] 
[junit] Running com.cisco.sdp.core.vsn.ConnectivityServiceUTest 
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec 
[junit] Test com.cisco.sdp.core.vsn.ConnectivityServiceUTest FAILED (crashed) 
[echo] Emma code coverage result is in C:\Users\irfkhan2\SDP\platform\core\test\build\test\coveragereport\platform-core_coverage.ec
```

while running Junit test cases

Comment: Looks like there is a process wich uses the Address `Address already in use`

Comment: sir how i can resolve this issue could you please tell me by exmple

Comment: change the address or kill the process that has reserved the address

Comment: i have just killed that process which were using by 8080 port and working fine now

Comment: thanks a lot to all of the who answer